# Discord.net not working on linux

Tags: c#, linux, bots, discord, discord.net

I'm trying to get a discord bot coded in discord.net running on a linux VPS, I'm running via mono but I keep getting this error

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Exception: Connection lost
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x7f0ad80016d0 + 0x00029> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Discord.TaskManager.ThrowException () <0x419160b0 + 0x00065> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Discord.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket.WaitForConnection (CancellationToken cancelToken) <0x4192a2a0 + 0x000af> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Discord.Net.WebSockets.GatewaySocket.WaitForConnection (CancellationToken cancelToken) <0x4192a1b0 + 0x000c3> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Discord.DiscordClient+<BeginConnect>d__78.MoveNext () <0x41836df0 + 0x01406> in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x7f0ad80016d0 + 0x00029> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Discord.DiscordClient+<BeginConnect>d__78.MoveNext () <0x41836df0 + 0x01abe> in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x7f0ad80016d0 + 0x00029> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff6b0 + 0x000a7> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff630 + 0x0006b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff5e0 + 0x0003a> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () <0x7f0ad7fffb10 + 0x00012> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Discord.DiscordClient+<Connect>d__77.MoveNext () <0x41836560 + 0x002b1> in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x7f0ad80016d0 + 0x00029> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff6b0 + 0x000a7> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff630 + 0x0006b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff5e0 + 0x0003a> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () <0x7f0ad7fff5c0 + 0x00012> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MiXBot.Program+<>c+<<Main>b__1_3>d.MoveNext () <0x41835e40 + 0x001bd> in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x7f0ad80016d0 + 0x00029> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff6b0 + 0x000a7> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff630 + 0x0006b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff5e0 + 0x0003a> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () <0x7f0ad7fff5c0 + 0x00012> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Discord.DiscordClient.ExecuteAndWait (System.Func`1 asyncAction) <0x41835b00 + 0x00086> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MiXBot.Program.Main (System.String[] args) <0x417fbf60 + 0x002a3> in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Exception: Connection lost
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x7f0ad80016d0 + 0x00029> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Discord.TaskManager.ThrowException () <0x419160b0 + 0x00065> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Discord.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket.WaitForConnection (CancellationToken cancelToken) <0x4192a2a0 + 0x000af> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Discord.Net.WebSockets.GatewaySocket.WaitForConnection (CancellationToken cancelToken) <0x4192a1b0 + 0x000c3> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Discord.DiscordClient+<BeginConnect>d__78.MoveNext () <0x41836df0 + 0x01406> in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x7f0ad80016d0 + 0x00029> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Discord.DiscordClient+<BeginConnect>d__78.MoveNext () <0x41836df0 + 0x01abe> in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x7f0ad80016d0 + 0x00029> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff6b0 + 0x000a7> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff630 + 0x0006b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff5e0 + 0x0003a> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () <0x7f0ad7fffb10 + 0x00012> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Discord.DiscordClient+<Connect>d__77.MoveNext () <0x41836560 + 0x002b1> in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x7f0ad80016d0 + 0x00029> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff6b0 + 0x000a7> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff630 + 0x0006b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff5e0 + 0x0003a> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () <0x7f0ad7fff5c0 + 0x00012> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MiXBot.Program+<>c+<<Main>b__1_3>d.MoveNext () <0x41835e40 + 0x001bd> in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x7f0ad80016d0 + 0x00029> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff6b0 + 0x000a7> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff630 + 0x0006b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7f0ad7fff5e0 + 0x0003a> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () <0x7f0ad7fff5c0 + 0x00012> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Discord.DiscordClient.ExecuteAndWait (System.Func`1 asyncAction) <0x41835b00 + 0x00086> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MiXBot.Program.Main (System.String[] args) <0x417fbf60 + 0x002a3> in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have mono and .net core installed and I'm running it through mono.

Any suggestions? (I'd like to stick with discord.net if possible)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to take a stab at the solution because I didn't see you mention that you installed dotnet core on linux.   Here is a guide that has a checklist to follow your steps to make sure it's working correctly.  Discord.net appears to be in .net core.

If it still fails after that, try running other .net core apps on your linux server and see if those work.  I hope this helps!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume due to lack of context that you built your application using `.Net Framework` to which I can recommend you switch to `.Net Core`.

Afterwhich as mentioned by Solarcloud ensure you have `Dotnet Core` installed on your Linux box and then you can simply run it by `dotnet MyApplication.dll` after you build it, navigate to the folder etc.

Answer (score 0):

as per the docs it doesn't support mono

> Using this library with Mono is not supported until further notice. It is known to have issues with the library's WebSockets implementation and may crash the application upon startup.
>   https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/getting_started/installing.html?tabs=vs-install%2Ccore2-1

It runs perfectly fine on linux if you target `.net core` since d.net targets `.net standard`

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the docs (https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/getting_started/installing.html), it's not possible to run Discord.Net with Mono.

I suggest you to switch to **.NET Core**. When you'll now compile the code, it will output a .dll file (and regular .exe if 3.1+)

Download .NET Core runtime on your distribution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux

Once it's installed you should be able to run the .dll file with the following command in the terminal:
`dotnet <path_to_dll>`