# Required library at /natives/linux-arm/libconnect.so

Tags: java, linux, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, discord

I'm working on my own Discord-Bot using java. I added the feature to use it as a Music-Bot. Now i wanted to add an Volume command. I added the command in my program. Everything worked fine on my Microsoft Windows computer. I copied the bot to my Raspberry Pi 3 because i want to use the Raspberry as my Discord-Bot Server. I started the bot but now i get the error that the library "/natives/linux-arm/libconnect.so" is missing.

I'm using the lava-player on my Bot.

How can i fix that Problem?
Thank you for helping me. I'm still a "newbie" on programming and i'm very thankful for every help

Edit:

Error List

[`Pastebin`](https://pastebin.com/raw/qsDMKgXK)

Exception in thread "lava-daemon-pool-playback-1-thread-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Required library at /natives/linux-arm/libconnector.so was not found
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.NativeLibLoader.extractLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:93)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.NativeLibLoader.load(NativeLibLoader.java:77)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.ConnectorNativeLibLoader.loadConnectorLibrary(ConnectorNativeLibLoader.java:17)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.opus.OpusDecoderLibrary.getInstance(OpusDecoderLibrary.java:14)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.natives.opus.OpusDecoder.(OpusDecoder.java:21)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.common.OpusPacketRouter.initialiseDecoder(OpusPacketRouter.java:183)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.common.OpusPacketRouter.checkDecoderNecessity(OpusPacketRouter.java:167)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.common.OpusPacketRouter.process(OpusPacketRouter.java:84)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaOpusTrackConsumer.consume(MatroskaOpusTrackConsumer.java:47)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.processFrameInBlock(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:370)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.parseClusterSimpleBlock(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:334)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.parseNextCluster(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:319)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaStreamingFile.provideFrames(MatroskaStreamingFile.java:295)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaAudioTrack.lambda$process$0(MatroskaAudioTrack.java:39)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.executeProcessingLoop(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:248)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.container.matroska.MatroskaAudioTrack.process(MatroskaAudioTrack.java:38)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.DelegatedAudioTrack.processDelegate(DelegatedAudioTrack.java:27)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.source.youtube.YoutubeAudioTrack.processStatic(YoutubeAudioTrack.java:75)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.source.youtube.YoutubeAudioTrack.process(YoutubeAudioTrack.java:67)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.LocalAudioTrackExecutor.execute(LocalAudioTrackExecutor.java:90)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayerManager.lambda$executeTrack$1(DefaultAudioPlayerManager.java:348)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

I made my bot in C# but I had a similar problem(meaning missing files). when I wanted to extract my bot as an EXE I forgot some necessary files like:

```
Discord.Net.Commands.dll
Discord.Net.Commands.xml
Discord.Net.Core.dll
Discord.Net.Core.xml
Discord.Net.Rest.dll
...    and much more....
```

but I also had a problem with the connections.

[I commented about discord connection problem here C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058328/discord-net-not-working-on-linux/45782988#45782988)

but I don't know tho... I just wanted to help but don't know how much of a help I was but don't hate me because I'm a C# programmer committing about java. only wanted to help.

Comment: Thanks you for your help I could try to write the bot in C# would cost some time tho thank you and don't worry i don't hate you. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Seuma, I didn't mean that you should make the bot i C#, I don't know if it would work on Linux but if you do i can provide with a base for you to build on.         https://mega.nz/#!uZkUSILY!noE6BAAHGLXBilCBNSbWOuHy-XJfDVUrUpwv-P7HhFw

Comment: I wanted to do an update on this request: I had to  download the libconnector.so, open the .java file with 7zip and place it into the right folder for it. That was everything. After i did that everything worked fine for me.